# UIWebView, goBack accessing back-forward list?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I am just having a quick look at UIWebView and have written a small browser with a back button, a UITextField and a forward button. Here is what happens:

1. I enter "www.google.com" into the textField and it goes to the page.
2. The textField says "www.google.com"
3. I enter "www.apple.com" and it goes to the page.
4. The textField says "www.apple.com"
5. I tap the back button and return to "www.google.com"
6. The textField still says "www.apple.com"

I have added:

```
-(IBAction)myGoBack {
    NSLog(@"myGoBack ...");
    [webView goBack];
}
```

My question is, is there a way when I call goBack to access the location that is loaded from the back-forward list so that I can update my UITextFiled?

Gary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current URL from the UIWebView's request property and set the address bar text like this

```
- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *) webView {
    [addressBar setText:self.webView.request.URL.absoluteString];

}
```