# help with making a URL text field for my web browser iphone sdk?

Tags: ios4, uiwebview, uitextfield, nsurlrequest

I am making a web browser for my iphone app (this is just to try I won't be releasing it)...I wanted to know how can I make uitextfield update the url as I click on a link or when the website redirects you. Need some help please

Comment: You doing great till what stage? i mean where is the actual problem? adding the UITextField? or fill it with the current URL? what is your problem?

Comment: I have been able to add a uitextfield and then when I put in a web site the web view loads it but now when say suppose I search google for something the url in the text field doesn't update or say suppose I put in a tinyurl.com that redirects to another web site the url in the text bar doesn't update according to the web site

Comment: @user655995: please see my below answer the second link specifically .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create your own UITextField and add it in the top of the browser, with a cute Go! button to be able to navigate to another page you can hide the UItextfield with animation to the top of the View.

This will help you understanding the Padding thing:

[How to make a UITextField move up when keyboard is present?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present)

and Understanding the Forwards and backward mechanism you may want to look here:

[UIWebView, goBack accessing back-forward list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103294/uiwebview-goback-accessing-back-forward-list)

Comment: I have been able to do that but please  read the comment I have put above :)

Comment: @user655995: can you please post the code that is not working as an update to your Question.